# How to fix routing with pagination and long variable query strings

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a problem going from page one to page two, three, four, etc... when using pagination along with a long and variable query string.  I suspect its a routing issue.  I’m using a custom query that the user selects with a series of dropdown menus.   The resulting url is very long which contains all of the post variables.

For example, the working first page url looks like (with the post variables represented here as letters):

```
project/web/s/search_results/t/u/v/w/x/y/z
```

...and the non-working 2nd page url when page 2 is clicked:

```
project/web/s/search_results?page=2
```

The 2nd page is following the routing rule.  As mentioned page two doesn’t work as clicked from the pager menu.  But if I manually type in:

```
project/web/s/search_results/t/u/v/w/x/y/z?page=2
```

-it does work.  The important lines of code are as follows:

Routing rule:

```
search_results:
  url:      /s/search_results
  param:    { module: s, action: search_results }
```

url_for helper in pagination:

```
<?php foreach ($pager->getLinks() as $page): ?>
      <?php if ($page == $pager->getPage()): ?>
        <?php echo $page ?>
      <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo url_for('@search_results', $object) ?>?page=<?php echo $page ?>"><?php echo $page ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And the error message:

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
Unable to find the s object with the following parameters "array ( 'id' => 'search_results', 'sf_format' => 'html',)").
```

Should I be using a collection for the routing rule?

Edit:
The object referred to in the url_for helper:

```
<?php  foreach ($pager->getResults() as $o => $object):  ?>
```

Comment: Regarding your `url_for` that generate the pagination, you will always lost all your parameter since you don't re-add them. Why do you add `$object` to the `url_for` since the route isn't related to an object?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I posted the $object reference in an edit above.  I believe it's required for pagination, is it not?

Comment: Well, when you build your pagination, you are outside the `foreach` for the result. Otherwise you will have a pagination for each result :) I don't think you need to path `$object` to the `url_for`. For the rest, you will have to manually re-add all query parameters to each link inside the pagination. You see?

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the answer (manually re-adding the parameters)... it's going to be a pain to add them manually.

Comment: Yep ... You still can retrieve the request URI using `$sf_request->getUri()` but you will have to parse them, etc ..

Comment: ah... well that actually helps a lot.  I wasn't familiar with getUri().  Do I just do a strlen(), chopping off the front portion I don't need, and then inserting the result into the url_for() ? i.e. url_for('s/search_results/$strlenResult'); ?

Comment: Oh, you should use `getPathInfo` instead of `getUri`, it will retrieve all parameter (not the host, etc ..). And it will be more secure to explode them (by `/`) and pick parameter you want, you can build an array with all valid parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 <a href="<?php echo url_for(sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri()) ?>?page=<?php echo $page ?>"><?php echo $page ?></a>
```

Comment: OMG.  Genius. I've been messing with this all day.  I knew there had to be an easier way.  Thank you so much!  ++